# Is there any way to run a process on selected columns but keep the columns in the dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I am using `pandas.DataFrame` with 85 columns. I want to run a process on 84 of the columns and keep the 85th column unchanged. I don't want to drop or delete the 85th column. Here is the process I am trying:

```
normalized_df = (df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code, using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for selecting only columns you want to run process on:

```
UNWANTED_COL_NAME = 'name_of_unwanted_column'
touchable_columns = [col for col in df.columns if col != UNWANTED_COL_NAME]

normalized_df = (df[touchable_columns] - df[touchable_columns].min()) / (df[touchable_columns].max() - df[touchable_columns].min())
normalized_df[UNWANTED_COL_NAME] = df[UNWANTED_COL_NAME]
```

Comment: I want to keep the column in the new data frame. your code excludes the column.

Comment: I am sorry. I misunderstood the question. Have a look. I edited the answer.

Comment: There is an issue I am facing now, my dataset has some column with all zero (0) values. This code removes all the zeros from the cell and keeps the cells empty.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to skip last column (85th) only for that you can skip last columns using slicing like `df.iloc[:,:-1]` for operation and then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) last column with result.
Ex.:

```
normalized_df = (df.iloc[:,:-1]-df.iloc[:,:-1].min())/(df.iloc[:,:-1].max()-df.iloc[:,:-1].min()).join(df.iloc[:,-1])
```